# RStudio: Cannot view the trees generated by the tree and rpart functions

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I am trying to construct decision trees on the Heart Disease UCI dataset, using the rpart and tree functions in R.

The code is executing fine, and it is printing the edges of the tree, but not the nodes and their values. I didn't have any problem with ctree though. Code is given below:

```
library(rpart)
routp.tree <- rpart(num ~.,data1,method = "class")
plot(routp.tree)

library(tree)
tree_modeldei <- tree(num ~.,data1)
plot(tree_modeldei)
```

[image: https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/images/ctree.png]

I am expecting an output like the above, but getting the same tree with no text at all, no splitting criteria, no of nodes etc. is being displayed. Just the lines which are the edges of the tree. I think this could also be a problem with RStudio, its not able to display it properly. I tried saving the resultant tree as an image, but it was saving it in the same way as it was showing, lines without any text. Can someone please help?
Thanks

Comment: Look at `text.tree` If you run `?tree`, the example in the help file shows how to add text to the plot.

Comment: That worked fine! Thank you